# Deja Dup: `Unable to find the server at www.googleapis.com` and `FileNotUploadedError is not defined` during upload

Tags: backup, flatpak

(Note: I'm going to post this as a bug report on Launchpad, but I'm posting here too because I found a work-around that I wanted to share in case others are in my situation.)

I've recently installed Pop_OS 20.04 and installed Deja Dup from the software center (the `flatpak` version - 42.0, Jun 24 2020).

I have about 270k files which take up 45GB of space. I set up the Google Drive authentication successfully, and have more than enough free space on Google Drive (about 1.5TB of free space). I'm backing up all of my user home folder except `.cache`, Trash, and a few other things.

I'm using a password to encrypt the files, in case that matters at all.

The first time I tried, it uploaded about 50% of the data, and then it gave an error message that said "timed out" at the bottom of the error message, with a trace that mentioned `socket.timeout` near the bottom of the trace, and `with_tempdir` near the top. Unfortunately I didn't keep a copy of that error message.

The second time I tried, I was tracking network connectivity (using this simple web app: [Internet Connectivity Monitoring](https://isp-monitor.appspot.com/#na)), and got a `error-wifi-timeout - local network is issue` that coincided with the following Deja Dup `'FileNotUploadedError' is not defined` error:

```
Traceback (innermost last):
  File "/app/bin/duplicity", line 104, in <module>
    with_tempdir(main)
  File "/app/bin/duplicity", line 90, in with_tempdir
    fn()
  File "/app/lib/python3.7/site-packages/duplicity/dup_main.py", line 1531, in main
    do_backup(action)
  File "/app/lib/python3.7/site-packages/duplicity/dup_main.py", line 1655, in do_backup
    full_backup(col_stats)
  File "/app/lib/python3.7/site-packages/duplicity/dup_main.py", line 561, in full_backup
    config.backend)
  File "/app/lib/python3.7/site-packages/duplicity/dup_main.py", line 442, in write_multivol
    (tdp, dest_filename, vol_num)))
  File "/app/lib/python3.7/site-packages/duplicity/asyncscheduler.py", line 149, in schedule_task
    return self.__run_synchronously(fn, params)
  File "/app/lib/python3.7/site-packages/duplicity/asyncscheduler.py", line 175, in __run_synchronously
    ret = fn(*params)
  File "/app/lib/python3.7/site-packages/duplicity/dup_main.py", line 441, in <lambda>
    vol_num: put(tdp, dest_filename, vol_num),
  File "/app/lib/python3.7/site-packages/duplicity/dup_main.py", line 320, in put
    backend.put(tdp, dest_filename)
  File "/app/lib/python3.7/site-packages/duplicity/backend.py", line 393, in inner_retry
    code = _get_code_from_exception(self.backend, operation, e)
  File "/app/lib/python3.7/site-packages/duplicity/backend.py", line 353, in _get_code_from_exception
    return backend._error_code(operation, e) or log.ErrorCode.backend_error
  File "/app/lib/python3.7/site-packages/duplicity/backends/pydrivebackend.py", line 236, in _error_code
    if isinstance(error, FileNotUploadedError):
 NameError: name 'FileNotUploadedError' is not defined
```

On my third attempt, I uninstalled and reinstalled Deja Dup (still the flatpack version), and after 760 `.gpg`. files (25mb each) were uploaded (19GB, total), I got the following `Unable to find the server at www.googleapis.com` message. The connectivity tracker didn't detect any network problems this time - but note that it's only a very primivite "polling" thing that tests every 2 seconds. That said, I have a very reliable connection which consistently gives me 80Mbps, and down-time is very rare, so it seems like it's unlikely that it actually has to do with a faulty internet connection.

```
Traceback (innermost last):
  File "/app/bin/duplicity", line 104, in <module>
    with_tempdir(main)
  File "/app/bin/duplicity", line 90, in with_tempdir
    fn()
  File "/app/lib/python3.7/site-packages/duplicity/dup_main.py", line 1518, in main
    action = commandline.ProcessCommandLine(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/app/lib/python3.7/site-packages/duplicity/commandline.py", line 1192, in ProcessCommandLine
    backup, local_pathname = set_backend(args[0], args[1])
  File "/app/lib/python3.7/site-packages/duplicity/commandline.py", line 1063, in set_backend
    config.backend = backend.get_backend(bend)
  File "/app/lib/python3.7/site-packages/duplicity/backend.py", line 223, in get_backend
    obj = get_backend_object(url_string)
  File "/app/lib/python3.7/site-packages/duplicity/backend.py", line 209, in get_backend_object
    return factory(pu)
  File "/app/lib/python3.7/site-packages/duplicity/backends/pydrivebackend.py", line 102, in __init__
    file_list = self.drive.ListFile({u'q': u"'Root' in parents and trashed=false"}).GetList()
  File "/app/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pydrive/apiattr.py", line 162, in GetList
    for x in self:
  File "/app/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pydrive/apiattr.py", line 146, in __next__
    result = self._GetList()
  File "/app/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pydrive/auth.py", line 61, in _decorated
    self.auth.Authorize()
  File "/app/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pydrive/auth.py", line 523, in Authorize
    self.service = build('drive', 'v2', http=self.http)
  File "/app/lib/python3.7/site-packages/googleapiclient/_helpers.py", line 134, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/app/lib/python3.7/site-packages/googleapiclient/discovery.py", line 225, in build
    requested_url, discovery_http, cache_discovery, cache, developerKey
  File "/app/lib/python3.7/site-packages/googleapiclient/discovery.py", line 282, in _retrieve_discovery_doc
    resp, content = http.request(actual_url)
  File "/app/lib/python3.7/site-packages/oauth2client/transport.py", line 175, in new_request
    redirections, connection_type)
  File "/app/lib/python3.7/site-packages/oauth2client/transport.py", line 282, in request
    connection_type=connection_type)
  File "/app/lib/python3.7/site-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1976, in request
    cachekey,
  File "/app/lib/python3.7/site-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1640, in _request
    conn, request_uri, method, body, headers
  File "/app/lib/python3.7/site-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1553, in _conn_request
    raise ServerNotFoundError("Unable to find the server at %s" % conn.host)
 httplib2.ServerNotFoundError: Unable to find the server at www.googleapis.com
```

I restarted my computer, and had a fourth attempt. This time it saved 534 25MB files to Google Drive, and then gave the exact same error message as above.

On my fifth and final attempt it got to 171 files and then gave  the `'FileNotUploadedError' is not defined` error. This error once again coincided with the `timeout-wifi-timeout` error from the connectivity monitor.

Answer (score 2):

A temporary work-around that I found here: [Error using Backups in Ubuntu 18.10 (it was Deja Dup)](https://askubuntu.com/a/1127520/986830) was to remove the `flatpak` version (or snap, if you're using that) and install the `deb` version (which was 40.7, as of writing). It worked flawlessly, first time. It does mean you'll be using an older, less-polished UX, but so far as I can see that's the only significant difference.

#### Edit: [This bug has been fixed](https://bugs.launchpad.net/deja-dup/+bug/1887688/comments/1) and the fix has been published in the flatpak and snap releases of Deja Dup.